# Nested higher order messages in Laravel Collections

Tags: laravel, collections, functional-programming

Is there a reason why one cannot nest [higher order messages](https://laravel.com/docs/master/collections#higher-order-messages) in Laravel Collections?

For example, if you have 3 nested collections and you wish to apply a transformation to the inner ones, the following does not work, because the nested `->map->map` incurs in some kind of undefined condition:

```php
$collection->map->map->keyBy('id')
//           ^^^^^^^^
```

The only way I found to make it work is to use one higher order message only, and replace the inner one with a regular `map()` method call:

```php
$collection->map->map(fn($coll) => $coll->keyBy('id'))
//           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Full example:

```php
$data = [
  ['id1'=>100, 'id2'=>10, 'id3'=>1, 'value'=>111],
  ['id1'=>100, 'id2'=>10, 'id3'=>2, 'value'=>112],

  ['id1'=>100, 'id2'=>20, 'id3'=>1, 'value'=>121],
  ['id1'=>100, 'id2'=>20, 'id3'=>2, 'value'=>122],
];

$DOES_NOT_WORK = collect($data)
    ->groupBy(['id1', 'id2'])
    ->map->map->keyBy('id3')
    ->toArray();

$WORKS = collect($data)
    ->groupBy(['id1', 'id2'])
    ->map->map(fn ($coll) => $coll->keyBy('id3'))
    ->toArray();

$EXPECT = [
  100 => [
    10 => [
      1 => [
        "id1" => 100,
        "id2" => 10,
        "id3" => 1,
        "value" => 111,
      ],
      2 => [
        "id1" => 100,
        "id2" => 10,
        "id3" => 2,
        "value" => 113,
      ],
    ],
    20 => [
      1 => [
        "id1" => 100,
        "id2" => 20,
        "id3" => 1,
        "value" => 121,
      ],
      2 => [
        "id1" => 100,
        "id2" => 20,
        "id3" => 2,
        "value" => 122,
      ],
    ],
  ],
];
```

Comment: isn't `map()` a method?

Comment: @Pourbahrami Yes, but it is also a "higher order message" when you use it without parentheses. See the documentation linked above.

Comment: ok but what's the point of using a map function without a callable?

Comment: @Pourbahrami `->map->map->keyBy('id')` is shorter and more legible than `->map(fn($coll) => $coll->map(fn($coll) => $coll->keyBy('id')))`, if it worked. Also I would like to understand why it's not working.